# Delete rows from Nattable

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, nebula, nattable

I want to implement a row deletion logic in a Nebula Nattable.
This is what I plan to do:

1. Add context menu to the Nattable which is described in http://blog.vogella.com/2015/02/03/nattable-context-menus-with-eclipse-menus/
2. Add an SWT Action to the menu which will implement the delete

my question is, which is the best way to accomplish this:

- Should I delete the corresponding value from my data model and the table view is refreshed when I execute `this.natview.refresh();`?
  **OR**
- Should I get the rows from `SelectionLayer` and delete them (if so how do I do ?)?
  **OR**
- is there any default support for this function through `IConfiguration`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In NatTable you would typically do the following:

1. Create a command for deleting a row

   ```
   public class DeleteRowCommand extends AbstractRowCommand {

       public DeleteRowCommand(ILayer layer, int rowPosition) {
           super(layer, rowPosition);
       }

       protected DeleteRowCommand(DeleteRowCommand command) {
           super(command);
       }

       @Override
       public ILayerCommand cloneCommand() {
           return new DeleteRowCommand(this);
       }

   }
   ```
2. Create a command handler for that command

   ```
   public class DeleteRowCommandHandler<T> implements ILayerCommandHandler<DeleteRowCommand> {

       private List<T> bodyData;

       public DeleteRowCommandHandler(List<T> bodyData) {
           this.bodyData = bodyData;
       }

       @Override
       public Class<DeleteRowCommand> getCommandClass() {
           return DeleteRowCommand.class;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean doCommand(ILayer targetLayer, DeleteRowCommand command) {
           //convert the transported position to the target layer
           if (command.convertToTargetLayer(targetLayer)) {
               //remove the element
               this.bodyData.remove(command.getRowPosition());
               //fire the event to refresh
               targetLayer.fireLayerEvent(new RowDeleteEvent(targetLayer, command.getRowPosition()));
               return true;
           }
           return false;
       }

   }
   ```
3. Register the command handler to the body DataLayer

   ```
   bodyDataLayer.registerCommandHandler(
           new DeleteRowCommandHandler<your type>(bodyDataProvider.getList()));
   ```
4. Add a menu item to your menu configuration that fires the command

   ```
   new PopupMenuBuilder(natTable)
           .withMenuItemProvider(new IMenuItemProvider() {

               @Override
               public void addMenuItem(NatTable natTable, Menu popupMenu) {
                   MenuItem deleteRow = new MenuItem(popupMenu, SWT.PUSH);
                   deleteRow.setText("Delete");
                   deleteRow.setEnabled(true);

                   deleteRow.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                       @Override
                       public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
                           int rowPosition = MenuItemProviders.getNatEventData(event).getRowPosition();
                           natTable.doCommand(new DeleteRowCommand(natTable, rowPosition));
                       }
                   });
               }
           })
           .build();
   ```

Using this you don't need to call `NatTable#refresh()` because the command handler fires a `RowDeleteEvent`. I also don't suggest to call `NatTable#refresh()` in such a case, as it might change and refresh more than it should and would not update other states correctly, which is done correctly by firing the `RowDeleteEvent`.

Note that the shown example deletes the row for which the context menu is opened. If all **selected** rows should be deleted, you should create a command handler that knows the `SelectionLayer` and retrieve the selected rows as shown in the other answer.

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution. Shouldn't you convert the position you get  from command.getRowPosition() to index before using it to remove from the data provider?

Comment: This is done in the command handler via command.convertToTargetLayer(). And as the command handler is the body DataLayer, index == position

Comment: Thanks for the step by step explanation Dirk. The only use of DeleteRowCommand class as I can see is that it provides the row position (though there could be more reasons ) to the command handler. So why can't we just have just the handler class. Essentially this is a Nattable framework question

Comment: Because the command is fired down the layer stack to trigger the command handler. And it provides the information which rows should be deleted. This is the concept of commands in NatTable as explained here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTable/article.html#architecture_commandsevents

Comment: can I perform the same delete for multiple rows ?

Comment: if you modify the command and the command handler to be able to handle multiple row positions, yes.

Answer (score 0):

In our application we do the following:

1. Get selected row objects:

   ```
   SelectionLayer selectionLayer = body.getSelectionLayer();
   int[] selectedRowPositions = selectionLayer.getFullySelectedRowPositions();
   Vector<Your Model Objects> rowObjectsToRemove = new Vector<Your Model Objects>();

   for (int rowPosition : selectedRowPositions) {
       int rowIndex = selectionLayer.getRowIndexByPosition(rowPosition);
       rowObjectsToRemove .add(listDataProvider.getRowObject(rowIndex));
   }
   ```
2. Remove them from the data provider
3. call `natTable.refresh()`