# How can I use RowInsertEvent for insert a new row in Nattable at runtime?

Tags: nattable

I assumed the solution will be like that answer 
[Delete rows from Nattable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907288/delete-rows-from-nattable)
but I can't edit `doCommand` to add one more argument for the object needed to be inserted as `doCommand` is an override method

```
public boolean doCommand(ILayer targetLayer, AddRowCommand command) {

            //convert the transported position to the target layer
            if (command.convertToTargetLayer(targetLayer)) {
                //remove the element
                this.bodyData.remove(command.getRowPosition());
                //fire the event to refresh
                targetLayer.fireLayerEvent(new RowInsertEvent(targetLayer, command.getRowPosition()));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to modify doCommand(). You need to modify your AddRowCommand to transport the objects you want to add.

Comment: i tried to edit my code but the table didn't refresh and didn't add "006;200541;ICMP;001;001;001;001"


AddRowCommand class

http://pastie.org/10715219#9

AddRowCommandHandler class
http://pastie.org/10715225#11


nattable view
http://pastie.org/10715233


// i don't know what i need to add here (ReceivingDataTable class)
http://pastie.org/10715450

Comment: You need to register your command handler to the DataLayer. I don't see that in your code. I also wonder if you really need the command handler approach. Is a user able to add a new entry via user interaction? Or do you want to update the list in a background process? For the background processing you simply need to add the model object to one of the GlazedLists instances.

Comment: i looked at your example github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/… an tried to edit class ReceivingDataTable pastie.org/10716936 and class NatTableView pastie.org/10716938#23 to operate directly on GlazedList eventList but the problem is that it added only one row .. and it needed to minimize the plugin then maximize to show the added row ... i tried to find my mistake but i failed

Comment: I can't access your code on pasti.org from here. But it sounds like there is no refresh triggered on updating the list. This typically means there is no GlazedListsEventLayer in your layer stack, which is used as a listener for GlazedLists list changes and triggers NatTable refresh events on that.