# Delete Multiple rows from Nattable

Tags: eclipse-rcp, nattable, nebula

I am trying to delete more than one row from `NatTable`. Following the solution described in [Delete rows from Nattable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907288/delete-rows-from-nattable). I have created a the following classes:
the Command class looks like this :

```
public class DeleteMultiRowCommand extends AbstractMultiRowCommand {

    public DeleteMultiRowCommand(AbstractMultiRowCommand command) {
        super(command);
    }

    protected DeleteMultiRowCommand(ILayer layer, int[] rowPositions) {
        super(layer, rowPositions);
    }

    @Override
    public ILayerCommand cloneCommand() {
        return new DeleteMultiRowCommand(this);
    }

}
```

Command Handler class:

```
public class DeleteMultiRowCommandHandler<T> implements ILayerCommandHandler<DeleteMultiRowCommand> {

    private List<T> bodyData;
    private SelectionLayer layer;

    public DeleteMultiRowCommandHandler(List<T> bodyData, SelectionLayer selectionLayer) {
        this.bodyData = bodyData;
        this.layer = selectionLayer;
    }

    public DeleteMultiRowCommandHandler(List<T> bodyData){
        this.bodyData = bodyData;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<DeleteMultiRowCommand> getCommandClass() {
        return DeleteMultiRowCommand.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean doCommand(ILayer targetLayer, DeleteMultiRowCommand command) {
        //convert the transported position to the target layer
        if (command.convertToTargetLayer(targetLayer)) {
            Collection<Integer>rowpos = command.getRowPositions();
            //remove the element
            for(Integer val : rowpos){
                this.bodyData.remove(val.intValue());
                targetLayer.fireLayerEvent(new RowDeleteEvent(targetLayer, val.intValue()));
            }

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

and the Command will be triggered on clicking a MenuItem

```
this.contextMenu = new PopupMenuBuilder(natTable)
            .withInspectLabelsMenuItem()
            .withClearAllFilters()
            .withColumnRenameDialog()
            .withMenuItemProvider(new IMenuItemProvider() {

                @Override
                public void addMenuItem(final NatTable natTable, Menu popupMenu) {
                    MenuItem deleteRow = new MenuItem(popupMenu, SWT.PUSH);
                    deleteRow.setText("Delete Row(s)");
                    deleteRow.setEnabled(true);

                    deleteRow.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() { 
                        @Override
                        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
                            //int rowPosition = MenuItemProviders.getNatEventData(event).getRowPosition();
                            ILayer bl = ((GridLayer)natTable.getLayer()).getBodyLayer();
                            BodyLayerStack bl1 = (BodyLayerStack) bl;
                            SelectionLayer sl = bl1.getSelectionLayer();
                            int []poss = new int[sl.getFullySelectedRowPositions().length];
                            int i=0;
                            for(int pos1 : sl.getFullySelectedRowPositions()){
                                poss[i]=sl.getRowIndexByPosition(pos1);
                                i++;
                            }
                            //System.out.println("Menu item selected "+rowPosition);
                            //natTable.doCommand(new DeleteRowCommand(natTable, rowPosition));
                            natTable.doCommand(new DeleteMultiRowCommand(natTable, poss));
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
            .build();
```

when I try to delete the rows, rows which not selected are deleted. Seems like an issue with the row postion to row index conversion. is the row postion to row index conversion correct within my `IMenuItemProvider` right ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you do the conversion from position to index twice: once in the menu item selection listener and once in the command handler (by calling `convertToTargetLayer`). The first is not necessary.

Comment: previously I was not using `getRowIndexByPosition` but that was causing the same issue of deleting some other row.

Answer (score 1):

That is not an issue of NatTable, but an issue on how to work with collections. You need to remove the items backwards if you remove the elements one by one. Otherwise the items for the indexes are changing while processing.

Let's assume you want to delete the elements at index 1 and 2. After removing the element at index 1, the elements below will move up. So the element that was before on index 2 will be on index 1 now, and the element at index 3 will be on index 2. Therefore the removal of the element at index 2 in the next iteration will remove the item that was before on index 3.

I'd suggest to sort and reverse the collection of indexes before iterating to remove items from the collection. Than it should work.

Comment: I changed my Commandhandler `doCommand` method to store the selected objects in a temporary `ArrayList` and then delete by the `ArrayList.remove(Object)` method. But still the issue happens. I have a Filter row as well. I could also notice that the method `command.convertToTargetLayer(targetLayer)` is returning false if I try deleting the first row.

Comment: If the issue is still present with that approach, you are operating on the wrong list. I suppose the table shows the FilterList contents but you are operating on the base list. You should check that you operate on the same list instance.

Comment: This is how I am creating the CommandHandler: `List data = ((ListDataProvider)bodyLayerStack.getBodyDataProvider()).getList();
  bodyLayerStack.getBodyDataLayer().registerCommandHandler(new DeleteRowCommandHandler(data,bodyLayerStack.getSelectionLayer()));
  bodyLayerStack.getBodyDataLayer().registerCommandHandler(new DeleteMultiRowCommandHandler(data));` I am using the FilterList to create the `BodyDataProvider`.

Comment: Sorry but I can't remote debug your code. Something is not right with your composition with regards to the collections. You need to debug and check the collections and their content compared to what you want to remove.

Comment: If I dont use `getRowIndexByPosition`, (like suggested by @Arye Shemesh) it seems that the deletes are working for all rows except 1st and 2nd rows. Now the command looks like this `natTable.doCommand(new DeleteMultiRowCommand(natTable, sl.getFullySelectedRowPositions()));`. Still need to figure out why 1st and 2nd rows can't be deleted.

Comment: I changed `new DeleteMultiRowCommand(natTable, selectionLayer.getFullySelectedRowPositions())` to `new DeleteMultiRowCommand(selectionLayer, selectionLayer.getFullySelectedRowPositions())`. Now the deletes work fine.