# Register commandHandler with EventList in a Nattable with Filters

Tags: nattable

As a suggestion from question [Nattable add row command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53080736/nattable-add-row-command) I tried to register a command handler with an `EventList`.

But since the `Eventlist` is wrapped by a `FilterList` which acts as `BodyDataProvider` I could not create a `DataLayer` based in `EventList` from which I could register my `CommmandHandler`.

The starting point is the previous question to define a `BodyLayerStack` with the following:

```java
class BodyLayerStack extends AbstractLayerTransform {
    //AncolabMaterial is the model to show at the natTable
    private final EventList<AncolabMaterial> filterList;
    private final IDataProvider bodyDataProvider;
    private final SelectionLayer selectionLayer;
    public BodyLayerStack(List<AncolabMaterial> input_values_list, IColumnPropertyAccessor<AncolabMaterial> columnPropertyAccessor) {
        EventList<AncolabMaterial> eventList = GlazedLists.eventList(input_values_list);
        TransformedList<?, ?> rowObjectsGlazedList = GlazedLists.threadSafeList(eventList);
        SortedList<?> sortedList = new SortedList<>(rowObjectsGlazedList, null);
        this.filterList = new FilterList<AncolabMaterial>((EventList<AncolabMaterial>) sortedList);
        this.bodyDataProvider = new ListDataProvider<AncolabMaterial>(filterList, columnPropertyAccessor);
        DataLayer bodyDataLayer = new DataLayer(getBodyDataProvider());
        //Other layers stacked
        GlazedListsEventLayer<?> glazedListsEventLayer = new GlazedListsEventLayer<AncolabMaterial>(bodyDataLayer, this.filterList); 
        this.selectionLayer = new SelectionLayer(glazedListsEventLayer, false);
        //...
    }
}
```

I have tried the following:

```java
DataLayer dataLayer = new DataLayer(
    new ListDataProvider<AncolabMaterial>(eventList, columnPropertyAccessor));
```

But since `DataLayer` wraps the `IDataProvider`, and serves as the data source for all other layers, If I sets the `EvenList` as the `IDataProvider` of the `DataLayer` then `filterlList` is not working properly. 
i.e. `this.filterList` is not the base of the `bodyDataProvider`.

I have not find at nattable_examples -> tutorial examples -> GlazedLists -> Filter any other `BodyLayerStack` configuration different than the above.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a big misunderstanding with regards to the list instances. If you want to use the filter functionality the shown `BodyLayerStack` is correct. You have to use the `FilterList` in the `IDataProvider`. There is absolutely now reason to change that!

For the command handler you need to use the base `EventList` instance. Of course that does not work if you use the list that you get from the `IDataProvider`. You need to provide the access to the `EventList` in another way. From the snippets you show in this and in the other related post, I don't see a reason why you access the underlying list via `IDataProvider`, but as you already noticed, that does not work. You need to change your code structure.

Comment: I have got similar problem. I do use only sorting and filtering. But I do not understand, why filtering works and while I try to sort I get NullPointerException and RuntimeException. `PropertyDescriptor` is null in `ReflectiveColumnPropertyAccessor.class`

Comment: Can only be a problem in your setup. Double check the list and layer creation and compare it with the examples.